# generating master public key from address

Tags: public-key

I want to know is it possible to generate master public key from an address? if not, what is needed to generate xpub key?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.
An address is created though a hash160 (RIPEMD160) which is a one-way function.

Creating a xpub key (bip32 extended public key) requires the according pubkey and the `chaincode`.
Alternatively you can calculate an xpub from an xpriv (extended private key).